# How can I add items to an arraylist from parse snapshot in FirebaseFireStore Recycler options.?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add items to an arraylist from parse snapshot in Firebase Firestore?

Comment: This post is broad, please update your post and include more details. On the other hand you can browse some basic tutorial regarding the problem on firebase

Answer (score 1):

If I really understand what you mean

> Update elements in an array If your document contains an array field,
>   you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements.
>   arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already
>   present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element.
>
> ```
> DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");
>
> // Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
> washingtonRef.update("regions", FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia"));
>
> // Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
> washingtonRef.update("regions", FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast"));
> ```

More details from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)